# SELECT DISTINCT on one column and return multiple other columns in Oracle/TOAD

Tags: oracle, toad

My goal is to get a distinct for Clm_Pd_Amt column only and return all  other columns:

```
SELECT CLM_AMT,  PAID_DATE, MBR, DISTINCT CLM_PD_AMT
FROM MY_CLAIMS
WHERE DATE >= '20200101
AND STATUS = 'CURRENT'
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results to clarify your question. `DISTINCT` operates on an entire resultset at once, not on a column only.

Comment: You will need to explain what you have as input, at the very least an example, and what you would like as output, because when it comes to SQL, your request doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

A GROUP BY is equivalent to a distinct, for example, the distinct list of departments in the EMP table can be found with (say)

```
SQL> select deptno, min(sal)
  2  from emp
  3  group by deptno
  4  /

    DEPTNO   MIN(SAL)
---------- ----------
        30        951
        10       1300
        20        800
```

But what if I want to know *which* employee had that minimum salary.  Then you can use the KEEP clause to gather that as well, eg

```
SQL> select deptno, min(sal), min(empno) KEEP ( dense_rank FIRST order by sal) empno
  2  from emp
  3  group by deptno
  4  /

    DEPTNO   MIN(SAL)      EMPNO
---------- ---------- ----------
        10       1300       7934
        20        800       7369
        30        951       7900
```

So using that approach, you should be able to adapt your query to get the distinct CLM_PD_AMT and then pick up the other columns with KEEP.  This only works if you have a definition for *which* distinct CLM_PD_AMT means, ie, the smallest? the largest? etc